# Syncing Local Core Data DB with Web Service

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I've a simple web service providing my iOS project some JSON. I'm storing the retrieved data in a Core Data database for ease of use. It's all working fine.

Although I'm not sure how to setup syncing between the server and the iOS project. My aim is that the web service is the only data source and always has the up-to-date data. iOS client can't make any modifications to the web service. It can just retrieve data. Hence a deleted data on the web service should get deleted on the iOS side as well. Which currently does not.

How should I proceed? I saw some stuff on the web couldn't get my head around. A basic mechanism explanation would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The good approach should be something like this:

1. Keep a local copy of data if possible for first app launch.
2. when app launches check for version parameter i.e. if the locally saved data you have is updated or the server has fresh data.
3. If you have the updated data then no need to hit api to fetch data.
4. If server has the updated version, then hit the api and replaced the local data with fresh data and save.

Basically before you hit your data download API, you should have another API to check if the data present on the server is same as the local one and on that basis the download and update mechanism should be done.